# How to add a row into multiple tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to add a row into multiple tables pending on inheritance in mysql? For example, customers and admins are type users. how do I make it when I insert into customers/admins, it also adds into users?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support inheritance directly. Foreign Keys are used to imitate the Object-oriented design. One way to achieve what you want is to manually add the same row to two different tables (user and customer) in two separate queries.

If you want to automate the insertion to users, you could write a trigger to add the row into users:

```
create trigger ins_user after insert on customer
for each row
begin
insert into user values (new.customer_id, new.name, ...);
end;
```

**Note**. Postgresql supports the inheritance and has the behaviour you want. One table can inherit from the other. And once you add a row to the child table, the query of the parent will also contain the rows in all its children.